# How to check whether a certain day_id is contained inside a given time interval day_from to day_to?

Tags: postgresql, data-consistency

I am a rather inexperienced SQL developer but I am trying to do my best to have a consistent database. The problem I seek to resolve could be done in an upper layer of my system but I am aware that it's best to handle things like that where they belong: In the database layer.

So what I am having is a table where I store offers that may or may not repeat on a defined day:

```
day_of_week
---------------------------------------------
id  day_name
1   SUNDAY
2   MONDAY
3   TUESDAY
4   WEDNESDAY
5   THURSDAY
6   FRIDAY
7   SATURDAY

offer
---------------------------------------------
id  day_id   valid_from_day  valid_until_day
1   3        2016-03-01      2016-03-01
2   6        2016-03-01      9999-03-01
```

and here is my problem:

```
offer
---------------------------------------------
id  day_id   valid_from_day  valid_until_day
1   2        2016-03-01      2016-03-01
2   6        2016-03-01      9999-03-01
```

`day_id` 2 makes no sense for `2016-03-01` to `2016-03-01` because the 1st or March, 2016 was a `TUESDAY = 3`, not a `MONDAY = 2`.

I want to be able to store arbitrary intervals into this table but I have to make sure that they make sense. What I am looking for is a way to check whether a given interval `valid_from_day` to `valid_until_day` contains a given day `day_id`. This should actually be an easy check but I am not sure if I can use a `CONSTRAINT` for this or whether I'd have to use a `TRIGGER` for this and how that would look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think a trigger is best in this case. Write it so that an UPDATE or INSERT is done only if `day_id` is between `extract(dow from valid_from_day::date)` and `extract(dow from valid_until_day::date)`. This should fit naturally within how trigger functions work.

There are other variations you can use, check the [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html) function.